# Convert binary File to array of bytes

Tags: go

I'm wondering what is the best way to convert binary `File` to `[]byte`

Here is a sample code that doesn't work. I'm wondering how I should adjust it to return the content as

```
func ReadFileAndReturnByteArray(extractedFilePath string) ([]byte, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(extractedFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileinfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    filesize := fileinfo.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, filesize)

    _, err = file.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return  nil, err
    }
    return buffer, nil
}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile

Comment: A file is already an array of bytes.  All you have to do is read it.  Most operating systems don't distinguish between text and binary files, but even on those which do,   Go is going to read `[]byte`s from both.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "binary file" as there are no non-binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The os package provides a [ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile) function which only works for files. It has the exact same signature as your `ReadFileAndReturnByteArray` function and should be a drop-in replacement.

---

The io package provides the [ReadAll](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadFull) function which works for any `io.Reader`.

Example:

```golang
func ReadFileAndReturnByteArray(extractedFilePath string) ([]byte, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(extractedFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    return io.ReadAll()
}
```